# Sorting an key value in objects using Underscore JS

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I had Three objects in an array. I want every time the object should be sorted by the key value.

Every time i want large 1st,medium 2nd,and person 3rd.

```
[
    {
        available: true,
        description: "Description2",
        label: "Medium"
    },
    {
        available: true,
        description: "Description2",
        label: "Large"
    },
    {
        available: true,
        description: "Description2",
        label: "Person"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you make the screenshot bigger so we can see it?  Or better yet, can you copy & paste the text into the question instead of a screenshot?

Comment: P.S. Objects in JavaScript don't have a defined order.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Do you want an array that is always sorted, or just a way to sort an array of objects like the ones you have listed?

Comment: Can you please click on the image and then there is a zoom option..there is no option to the increase the screen shot

Comment: I want to sort the objects using the key value label@ chris hunt